# Arrays.fill() - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays

can someone explain to me why i get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range??

I have simple array, for example: {1,2,3,4,5}, i want to fill in index from 0 to before the last one by 0 : updated array should be like that {0,0,0,0,5}.

I try to us :

```
 public static int[] makeLast(int[] nums) {

    int size = nums.length;
    Arrays.fill(nums, nums[0], nums[size-2] ,0);
    return nums;
}
```

Unfortunatelly it causes me an error as above.

Comment: Wondering: do you still have questions regarding the answers you got? If not, and your problem is solved, please consider accepting one of the answer at some point.

Answer (score 3):

Read the corresponding [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(int%5B%5D,int,int,int)): the 3rd parameter is the last index to fill.
So the method "fills" from the first given **index** to that **index -1**

So you have to pass the **indexes** you care about, **not** the current content at those indexes!

```
Arrays.fill(nums, 0, size-1 ,0);
```

And note, the exception messages would have told you that you tried to access an invalid index. So the real answer is: read the exception messages carefully, and: read the javadoc for the library calls you are using even more carefully.

Comment: @GhostCat Note for `Arrays.fill(..)` that the first index is inclusive while the second index is _exclusive_.  I think you want the second index to be `size-1`.  OP should consider whether they need to handle the case where the array is null/empty.

Answer (score 1):

The ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException Happens when the developer call index is not found in the array, so I have checked the size of the array
and Marco needs to set all values of the array zeros except the last one.
the method fill works like this => Arrays.fill( ARRAY,FIREST_INDEX, LAST_IDNEX,VALUE) ;

```
 public static int[] makeLast(int[] nums) {
        int size = nums.length;
        if (size != 0) {
            Arrays.fill(nums, 0, size - 1, 0);
        }
        return nums;
    }
```

Comment: and the output of {1,2,3,4,5} array will be 0,0,0,0,5

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained why your code addresses the question.

Answer (score -1):

First, it is not working as substring to exclude the last index. It fills from first index given to second index given - included.

Second, if your input array is null, empty or contains only one entry, your method fails too.

And you pass the content there and not the actual index - so completely wrong use of the fill method.

```java
if (nums == null) return null;
int size = nums.length;
if (size > 1)
  Arrays.fill(nums, 0, size-1, 0);
```